# Certificate conflict

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, discourse

I recently deployed 2 websites (a discourse instance and regular html and css) on a digitalocean droplet.
Using letsencrypt, I generated security certificates for both. However, the one for the the discourse instance keeps conflicting with that of the regular website.
I ran a check on [ssllabs](https://ssllabs.com) and the `SNI` check keeps returning the discourse instance as the owner of the certificate for the regular.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: We'd need more details in order to help. What SANs did you put in each certificate? What is the current behavior, and what were you expecting? OS and web server version?

Comment: **OS**: Ubuntu 16.04, **Web Server Version**: Nginx 1.10.3. So I'm a little new to this so can you give me further explanation on SANs please? **Expectation**-wise, I didn't think the certificates will conflict and return one for the other as explained above. Thanks.

Comment: [Subject Alternative Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) is a field that allows you to enter multiple DNS names in a certificate. This would allow you to use a single certificate for multiple domains (e.g. `example.com`, `www.example.com`, and `foo.example.com`) instead of using a separate certificate for each. If you're serving  two sites from the same webserver on the same machine, you may be able to use a SAN certificate, depending on how you have them set up.

Comment: Thanks, I found problem. I was supposed to specify **all** the SANs together when creating the certificate.